# I keep getting an error that says "Compile error: For without Next"

Tags: excel, vba, loops, compilation

**Hello Everyone. I'm new to VBA and I keep getting an error that says "Compile error:
For without Next"**

```
Sub Aplhabetical_Testing()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ticker As String
Dim vol As Integer
Dim year_open As Double
Dim year_close As Double
Dim yearly_change As Double
Dim percent_change As Double
Dim total_stock_volume As Double


    For Each ws In Worksheet

        ws.Range("I1").Value = "Ticker"
        ws.Range("J1").Value = "Yearly Change"
        ws.Range("K1").Value = "Percent Change"
        ws.Range("L1").Value = "Total Stock Volume"
        
        ws.Range("P1").Value = "Ticker"
        ws.Range("Q1").Value = "Value"
        ws.Range("O2").Value = "Greatest % Increase"
        ws.Range("O3").Value = "Greatest % Decrease"
        ws.Range("O4").Value = "Greatest Total Volume"


    For i = 2 To RowCount
    j = 0
    total = 0
    Change = 0
    Start = 2
    
    
         If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 7).Value Then
            total = total + Cells(i, 7).Value
                    Range("I" & 2 + j).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
                    Range("j" & 2 + j).Value = 0
                    Range("K" & 2 + j).Value = "%" & 0
                    Range("L" & 2 + j).Value = 0
        Else
            If Cells(Start, 3) = 0 Then
                For find_value = Start To i
                    If Cells(find_value, 3).Value <> 0 Then
                            Start = find_value
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next find_value
End If

                
                Change = (Cells(i, 6) - Cells(Start, 3))
                percentChange = Round((Change / Cells(Start, 3) * 100), 2)
                Start = i + 1
                
                Range("I" & 2 + j).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
                Range("j" & 2 + j).Value = Round(Change, 2)
                Range("K" & 2 + j).Value = "%" & percentChange
                Range("L" & 2 + j).Value = total
                
                Select Case Change
                    Case Is > 0
                        Range("j" & 2 + j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                    Case Is < 0
                        Range("j" & 2 + j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    Case Else
                        Range("j" & 2 + j).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    End Select
      End If
      
      
 
          
          
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement

Comment: put a `Next` on the line before your `End Sub` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: one "Next" is not enough: there are 2 loops :) Also, there is an extra "End If" (one of the 2 showing... Quite careless,,,

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of statements in VBA which must be properly terminated. For instance,

Sub / End Sub,
Function / End Function,
If / End If.
With / End With, or
Enum / End Enum

For better code readability everything between the statement and the `End` should be indented, like this:-

```
Sub MySub()
    ' Here is my code
End Sub
```

or

```
If 1 < 2 Then
    ' Here is what to do in that case
End If
```

*For / Next* and *Do / Loop* work exactly the same way. For example,

```
For i = 1 to 10
    ' code to be executed *i* times
Next i
```

The concepts can be nested. Here's an example.

```
Private Sub MySub()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 to 10
        If i = 5 then
            Debug.Print "Half done"
        End if
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss two Next:

```vb
Sub Aplhabetical_Testing()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ticker As String
    Dim vol As Integer
    Dim year_open As Double
    Dim year_close As Double
    Dim yearly_change As Double
    Dim percent_change As Double
    Dim total_stock_volume As Double

    For Each ws In Worksheet    ' Worksheets?
        ws.Range("I1").Value = "Ticker"
        ws.Range("J1").Value = "Yearly Change"
        ws.Range("K1").Value = "Percent Change"
        ws.Range("L1").Value = "Total Stock Volume"
        
        ws.Range("P1").Value = "Ticker"
        ws.Range("Q1").Value = "Value"
        ws.Range("O2").Value = "Greatest % Increase"
        ws.Range("O3").Value = "Greatest % Decrease"
        ws.Range("O4").Value = "Greatest Total Volume"

        For i = 2 To RowCount
            j = 0
            total = 0
            Change = 0
            Start = 2
    
            If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 7).Value Then
                total = total + Cells(i, 7).Value
                Range("I" & 2 + j).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
                Range("j" & 2 + j).Value = 0
                Range("K" & 2 + j).Value = "%" & 0
                Range("L" & 2 + j).Value = 0
            Else
                If Cells(Start, 3) = 0 Then
                    For find_value = Start To i
                        If Cells(find_value, 3).Value <> 0 Then
                            Start = find_value
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next find_value
                End If
                
                Change = (Cells(i, 6) - Cells(Start, 3))
                percentChange = Round((Change / Cells(Start, 3) * 100), 2)
                Start = i + 1
                
                Range("I" & 2 + j).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
                Range("j" & 2 + j).Value = Round(Change, 2)
                Range("K" & 2 + j).Value = "%" & percentChange
                Range("L" & 2 + j).Value = total
                
                Select Case Change
                    Case Is > 0
                        Range("j" & 2 + j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                    Case Is < 0
                        Range("j" & 2 + j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    Case Else
                        Range("j" & 2 + j).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                End Select
            End If 
        ' Missing Next
        Next
    ' Missing Next
    Next

End Sub
```